# java exception handling

Tags: java

I need to retrieve data from db, if no data found in dB i need to fire a popup window in java. im giving the code here which i write to handle but unable to handle it.

```
String SectorCode = employerProfile.getSectorCode().getSectorTypeId();
String IndustrialCode = employerProfile.getIndustrialCode().getIndustryTypeId();
try{
    if(SectorCode==null || IndustrialCode==null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record not found" );
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please suggest me the solution...
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the actual problem?  Is it throwing an exception?  Are not seeing the dialog box?

Comment: yes its throwing exception... but user need to get popup window when there is no file exist in dB..

Comment: @charan ... when this call throw exception... May be incase of there is no record found ...?? M i ...?

Comment: What kind of exception is being thrown?

Comment: Null pointer exception... before it throws exception i need to fire a popup as there is no record.

Comment: THe NullpointerException will tell you at what line the problem is. Make sure you test for null there too, how do you retrieve your employerProfile ? if it isent in de DB , chances are the retrieval code will return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nasty way of doing it...(you mentioned that you are getting null pointer exception)

```
String SectorCode = null;
String IndustrialCode = null;
try{
  SectorCode = employerProfile.getSectorCode().getSectorTypeId();
  IndustrialCode = employerProfile.getIndustrialCode().getIndustryTypeId();
  ...
}catch(Exception ex){
    if(SectorCode==null || IndustrialCode==null){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record not found" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `if` block is not executed means an exception might be occuring in the method calls in the first 2 lines. Check if the lines  `employerProfile.getSectorCode().getSectorTypeId();`  and `employerProfile.getIndustrialCode().getIndustryTypeId();`  are executed properly without any exceptions.

Comment: No chaitanya. at first 2 lines there is no exception. but its unable to execute if block. At final in java console its showing null pointer exception

Comment: You are correct. if block will not be executed unless there is exception since if block is within try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you use and/or how it is set up you may need to check for empty strings, too:

```
if(SectorCode==null || IndustrialCode==null || SectorCode.length() == 0 || IndustrialCode.length() == 0) {
```